# Integrating Django with Amazon's Database 'SimpleDB'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

Can somebody guide me to develop a django app with SimpleDB(Amazon's Database) as its database. I couldnt find any tutorials on searching. Can somebody help me by explaining the process involved in integrating Django with SimplDB for creating a small application. Or if somebody have any tutorials for it, please share it with me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's any way to use Django's ORM with SimpleDB at the moment, unless you want to write all the code yourself. I'd suggest interfacing with SimpleDB using normal Python code (which would get called by your views or however you wish to do it).

To do this, use [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/). It's mature, stable and well-documented -- I used it quite successfully in a Django project I recently undertook.

Comment: okie..thanks for the reply Alistair :) i will try it with just Python .

Comment: How is it going?  I'm planning on doing the same thing.  I'm happy with Boto so far, but I'm not sure how to integrate into Django.

Answer (score 4):

There is now experimental support using [django-norel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) with the [django-simpledb](https://github.com/danfairs/django-simpledb) backend.